# Convert net mask into CIDR in Go

Tags: go

I'm looking for a way to convert a netmask string into CIDR notation in Go.

For instance, "255.255.255.0" -> "/24"

I'm currently obtaining an IP address and the net mask string with the below logic, which may just be complicating things.

I've been perusing the `net` library trying to see if there is a different function to use to accomplish what I'd like, which is really just a IP address in CIDR notation:

```
192.168.1.2/24
```

```
var mgmtInterface *net.Interface
var err error

mgmtInterface, err = net.InterfaceByName("eth0")
if err != nil {
  log.Println("Unable to find interface eth0, trying en0")
  mgmtInterface, err = net.InterfaceByName("en0")
}

addrs, err := mgmtInterface.Addrs()
if err != nil {
  log.Println("interface has no address")
}

for _, addr := range addrs {
  var ip net.IP
  var mask net.IPMask
  switch v := addr.(type) {
  case *net.IPNet:
    ip = v.IP
    mask = v.Mask
  case *net.IPAddr:
    ip = v.IP
    mask = ip.DefaultMask()
  }

  if ip == nil {
    continue
  }

  ip = ip.To4()
  if ip == nil {
    continue
  }

  // create the netmask
  cleanMask := fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", mask[0], mask[1], mask[2], mask[3])

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't very obvious at first, but:

```
addr := ip.To4()
sz, _ := net.IPV4Mask(addr[0], addr[1], addr[2], addr[3]).Size()
```

Comment: "IPV4Mask" should be "IPv4Mask", small letter v.

Comment: Couldn't you just use conversion like so (https://play.golang.org/p/blf5sv0Ncwz): `sz, _ := net.IPMask(ip.To4()).Size()`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware about existense of such function but it's easy to create one.

CIDR notation is just a count of set bits in netmask.

So, crude solution could be:

```golang
func cidr(netmask string) int {       
        var mask uint32
    for idx, dotpart := range strings.Split(netmask, ".") {
        part, _ := strconv.Atoi(dotpart)    
        mask = mask | uint32(part) << uint32(24-idx*8)
    }   
    return len(fmt.Sprintf("%b", mask))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward using the [IPAddress Go library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/).  Note that this code works equally well with both IPv4 and IPv6.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/seancfoley/ipaddress-go/ipaddr"
)

func main() {
    maskStr := "255.255.255.0"
    pref := ipaddr.NewIPAddressString(maskStr).GetAddress().
        GetBlockMaskPrefixLen(true)
    fmt.Printf("prefix length for %s is %d", maskStr, pref.Len())
}
```

Output:

```
prefix length for 255.255.255.0 is 24
```